# LORA ESP32 deepsleep time

Tags: arduino, esp32

I'm using an ESP32 with LORA (Arduino LMIC),
When I connect the LORA network my time in my ESP32 is set by the network.

When my ESP32 goes to "deep sleep" I need to know for how
many seconds, till it's 03:00 at night.

I'm trying to compare two times ("time now") and ("time to wake-up").
but it's not working, I don't know why...

```
  tmElements_t tm;

  tmElements_t tmConvert(byte hh, byte mm, byte ss)
  {
      tm.Hour = hh;
      tm.Minute = mm;
      tm.Second = ss;
      tm.Day = 1;
      tm.Month = 1;
      tm.Year = 1970;
      return tm;
  }

  unsigned long timeDiff(tmElements_t& tm1, tmElements_t& tm2)
  {
      return makeTime(tm2) - makeTime(tm1);
  }

  void test()
  {
      tmElements_t Time_wake = tmConvert(1, 0, 0);

      tmElements_t Time_now = tmConvert(18, 0, 0);

      int _diff = (timeDiff(Time_wake, Time_now));

      Serial.println("hours: ");
      Serial.print(_diff / 3600);
  }
```

Comment: *How* is it not working? Are you getting an error? If so, what is the error? An incorrect result? If so, what is the incorrect result and what result were you expecting to see? Exact numbers are much more helpful than "it's wrong", which doesn't give us anything to go on.

Answer (score 0):

I Solved it:

I must use date too,

if "time" is after midnight, date (day) must be the next day...